# bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-framework-beans

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of method `modifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory` in `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayAutoConfiguration` required a bean of type `'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer'` that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type `'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer'` in your configuration.

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook

Comment: It may because you include spring-boot-start-web jar through spring cloud gateway use spring-boot-starter-webflux instead. So remove spring-boot-start-web    may solve the problem.

Comment: Can you share your pom or gradle file?

Comment: Are you using jhipster?

Answer (score 24):

Try adding the below code. It worked for me

```
@Bean
public ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer() {
   return ServerCodecConfigurer.create();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me but only to configure basic security within gateway. I still needed to later replace `spring-boot-start-web` with `spring-boot-start-webflux`.

For anyone interested, there's a nice code samples at [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway)

Comment: Adding this bean creates a circular dependency for me; replacing 'web' with 'webflux' (also, it should be 'starter' not 'start') as mentioned in the comment, created errors for a class I had called 'LocaleConfiguration' which had imports coming from org.springframework.web.servlet

Answer (score 6):

You can try like this:

```
  compile ('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'){
        exclude module : 'spring-cloud-starter'
        exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Spring. Where do I add the code above to?

Comment: The answer refers to the gradle build system, you would make the changes to a file called build.gradle.  If your using mavin you would have to make changes to your pom.xml and use <exclusion> statement.

Comment: This may happen when your application is on a non-reactive stack and you import some libraries with a reactive stack that raise some beans into Spring context. Excluding reactive HTTP transitive dependencies will help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue building a spring cloud version `2020.0.0` and `Keycloak`, it seems that the `Keycloak` jar files includes a dependency on `spring-boot-start-web`
Telling maven NOT to include the default `spring-boot-start-web` as follows resolved that issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But I had to include a maven dependency to the `servlet` jar as to resolve some other requirements of `Keycloak` as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `application.properties` file, set this property
`spring.main.web-application-type=reactive`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In a setup where your parent app is in webflux but you are loading a dependency which is based on servlet, spring boot needs to know at the time of autoconfiguration about how to set up the parent app - as a reactive app or servlet based app. Since servlet is the default value for spring.main.web-application-type property, it treats the parent app as a Servlet based springboot app which leads to required components for reactive programming not being setup properly. Here it is the configurer which was not setup properly. Setting the prop as reactive, ensures proper component setup

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here but solution with

```
@Bean
public ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer() {
   return ServerCodecConfigurer.create();
}
```

only hid problem, and let application to compile. Anyway Somehow it made my Gateway not working correct. It didn't forward, log and response anything if I request with defined in `yaml` urls. Application just started and that's it.

In my case problem was `spring-boot-start-web` dependency. Accidently I didn't discover it, because in my project structure, my `build.gradle` inherits by "parent" and that parent implemented `spring-boot-start-web` in subprojects.

I removed that dependency and since than I requests were forwarded correctly and I saw logs. Than i removed `@Bean` with `ServerCodecConfigurer` .

Hope it could help anyone in same situation.

Configuration:
Spring boot:  2.4.4
Spring cloud: 2020.0.2

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I added the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

Pay attention if you are using Reactive Spring. I needed `HttpServletRequest` from this dependency, but now I'm using `ServerHttpRequest` from `org.springframework.http.server.reactive`.