# Exception : a bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-framework-beans

I am getting the below error in my program after adding the below maven dependencies.

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
```

Error

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations: {}

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' in your configuration.

Please suggest how to create org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer.

---

The issue is solved by adding the below code.

```
@Bean
public ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer() {
   return ServerCodecConfigurer.create();
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447223/bean-of-type-org-springframework-http-codec-servercodecconfigurer-that-could-n    or you could just do a search on org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer. .

Comment: Share the relevant code with more details and stacktrace

Comment: Share your full pom.xml

Comment: did u try link provided by @cliff2310

Comment: I have checked @cliff2310 link. I can't figure out how to execute that compile code. Can you please suggest.

Comment: Do a search opn  'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer'.  There lots of answers there/

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Spring Boot. Where do I add the @Bean to exactly? Is there a configuration file somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was caused by having both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` in my dependencies.

At the time of writing, both projects are not compatible: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/319