# Jhipster upgrade throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I upgraded a project using the command

```
npx jhipster upgrade --target-version 7.1.0
```

and in my gateway (the UI of my microservices project) I faced the following error

```
bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' that could not be found
```

I saw this post [bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447223/bean-of-type-org-springframework-http-codec-servercodecconfigurer-that-could-n) that advised me to change my dependency from spring-boot-start-web to spring-boot-start-webflux
(the first answer, where you add a 'ServerCodecConfigurer' bean, creates a circular dependency issue for me).

Now I get a new exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [oh.essentials.config.LocaleConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6295d394]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:903)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:891)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:878)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:819)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:349)
    at oh.essentials.OhEssentialsApp.main(OhEssentialsApp.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LocaleResolver
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LocaleResolver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Please let me know if you need any additional details. I also tried to re-run the jhipster import-jdl command to see if that would help, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: What version of JHipster are you upgrading from? The `upgrade` command doesn't always work between major releases. Especially microservices prior to v7. Mostly because the gateway is reactive-only in v7. This is a change we had to make based on Spring Cloud getting rid of Zuul and forcing Spring Cloud Gateway instead.

Comment: Does your JDL work if you use JHipster 7.8.1? If not, can you please update your question to include the JDL.

Comment: @MattRaible I am upgrading from v6.6 to v7.1.0. I have noticed in the release notes about how they got rid of zuul, I think this error is happening because I removed the spring-boot-starter-servlet dependency and replaced it with webflux to fix the ServerCodecConfigurer error